# AsyncTask finished execution

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I wonder how I could pause, cancel this function so I close the Activity that is running.

```
public class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
ImageView bmImage;

public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
    this.bmImage = bmImage;
}

protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
    String urldisplay = urls[0];
    Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
    try {
        InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
        mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return mIcon11;
}

protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
    bmImage.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
    bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
}}
```

How to call the function to cancel AsyncTask and InputStream

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing computations:

You have to check `isCancelled()` periodically.
If you're doing a HTTP request:

Save the instance of your `HttpGet` or `HttpPost` somewhere (eg. a public field).
After calling cancel, call `request.abort()`. This will cause `IOException` be thrown inside your `doInBackground`.
In my case, I had a connector class which I used in various `AsyncTask`s. To keep it simple, I added a new `abortAllRequests` method to that class and called this method directly after calling cancel.

Answer (score 0):

To cancel Bitmap loading, you can use the `requestCancelDecode` method of `BitmapFactory.Options`. Keep a reference to the Options object, and pass it to the `decodeStream` method. You can then call `requestCancelDecode` on the object to cancel the request. Android does indicate [calling the method does not guarantee that decoding actually gets cancelled](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#requestCancelDecode()).

Answer (score 0):

simply take a static variable whenever you want to cancel the asynctask just put static variable and return it in doingbackground.This is the safest way working with threads

```
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
   if(cancel)
{
return;
}
    String urldisplay = urls[0];
    Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
    try {
        InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();

        // ByteArrayOutputStream
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream(4048);

        // buffer
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4048];
        int bytesRead = -1;

        // isCancelled() == false is Important
        while ((isCancelled() == false) && (bytesRead = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }

        byte[] imageBytes = out.toByteArray();

        // Decode Bitmap from imageBytes
        if (isCancelled() == false) {
             mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.length);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return mIcon11;
}
```